# Usar una función para retornar variables

Tags: funciones, pseint

Tengo este código que separa cifras en PSeInt. Lo que quiero hacer es que la función contaryextraercifras(n) retorne en la variable resultado cada una de las cifras y que pasen al procedimiento mostrarcifras para mostrarlo en pantalla.

```
 Proceso Separarcifras_con_Subrocesos
    Definir n, resultado Como Enteros;
    Escribir "Ingrese un numero entero (puede ser positivo o negativo): ";
    Leer n;
    mostrarcifras(resultado);
FinProceso
    
SubProceso resultado <- contaryextraercifras(n)
    Definir i, digito, pot, aux, cont, resultado Como Enteros;
    cont <- trunc(logb10(abs(n)))+1;
    aux <- abs(n);
    Para i<-1 Hasta cont Con Paso 1 Hacer
        pot <- 10^(cont-i);
        digito <- trunc(aux/pot);
        aux <- aux-digito*pot;
        resultado <- digito;
    FinPara
FinSubProceso
    
SubProceso mostrarcifras(resultado)
    Escribir resultado," " Sin Bajar;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso Log10 <- Logb10 (valor)
    Definir Log10 Como Real;
    Log10 <- Ln(valor) / Ln(10);
FinSubProceso
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se debe hacer es definir resultado en el proceso principal y se lo debe llamar por referencia desde el subproceso mostrarcifras

```
Proceso Separarcifras_con_Subrocesos
    Definir n, digito, cont Como Enteros;
    Definir resultado Como Cadena;
    resultado <- "";
    digito <- 0;
    cont <- 0;
    Escribir "Ingrese un número entero (puede ser positivo o negativo): ";
    Leer n;
    resultado <- contaryextraercifras(n, digito, cont);
    mostrarcifras(cont, resultado);
FinProceso

SubProceso resultado <- contaryextraercifras (n, digito Por Referencia, cont Por Referencia)
    Definir i, pot, aux Como Enteros;
    Definir resultado Como Cadena;
    resultado <- "";
    cont <- trunc(logb10(abs(n)))+1;
    aux <- abs(n);
    Para i <- 1 Hasta cont Con Paso 1 Hacer
        pot <- 10^(cont-i);
        digito <- trunc(aux/pot);
        aux <- aux-digito*pot;
        resultado <- concatenar(concatenar(concatenar(resultado,concatenar("El dígito ", ConvertirATexto(i)))," es "),ConvertirATexto(digito));
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

SubProceso mostrarcifras(cont Por Referencia, resultado Por Referencia)
    Escribir "El número tiene ", cont , " dígitos";
    Escribir resultado;
FinSubProceso

SubProceso Log10 <- Logb10(valor)
    Definir Log10 Como Real;
    Si valor <> 0 Entonces
        Log10 <- Ln(valor) / Ln(10);
    SiNo
        Si valor < 0 Entonces
            Escribir "No existe logaritmo de negativo";
        Sino
            Escribir "No se puede calcular el logaritmo de 0";
        FinSi
    FinSi
FinSubProceso
```